# Use values from a column to run a SELECT statement Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to iterate through column values in a query.

```
Table1
index value

1, Nice
2, School
3, Day

Table2
index parent money

1, John, 100
2, Mary, 200
3, Mark, 300
```

pseudocode:

```
  FOR all values in Table1 
  SELECT  parent, function(value) 
  from Table2
```

The main problem lies in this function where I can only insert one value at a time.

Comment: and what problem are you having?

Comment: I'm having trouble with the syntax or method I would use

Comment: what does table2's structure look like?

Answer (score 3):

This does what your pseudocode asks:

```
SELECT
  Table2.parent,
  MyFunction(Table1.value) AS function_value
FROM Table2
CROSS JOIN Table1
```

Given your sample data, this query's results would be:

```
PARENT FUNCTION_VALUE
------ ---------------------------
John   value of function('Nice')
Mary   value of function('Nice')
Mark   value of function('Nice')
John   value of function('School')
Mary   value of function('School')
Mark   value of function('School')
John   value of function('Day')
Mary   value of function('Day')
Mark   value of function('Day')
```

This is because the query calls the function for *every row in* `Table1` *joined with every row in* `Table2`. If you have 8 rows in `Table1` and 10 rows in `Table2`, you'll get 80 results (8 x 10). If you have 1,000 rows in each table you'll get 1 million results (1,000 x 1,000).

If the `Index` column in each table is used to relate rows, try this instead:

```
SELECT
  Table2.parent,
  MyFunction(Table1.value) AS function_value
FROM Table2
JOIN Table1 ON Table2.index = Table1.index
```

With your sample data, the output from this query would be:

```
PARENT FUNCTION_VALUE
------ ---------------------------
John   value of function('Nice')
Mary   value of function('School')
Mark   value of function('Day')
```

If neither of these queries do what you need, please provide sample results.